# can we turn off dithering in ffmpeg for audio conversion

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Hi is it possible to turn off dithering in ffmpeg while doing audio format conversion. I came across a switch called dither_scale, which can be set to 0 while resampling. But I don't know how to turn off dithering while converting to different file format (16 bit PCM)

Comment: What's the command you are currently using? And input format?

Comment: ffmpeg -y -i input_file output_file.wav. I'm using speex, 16kHz mono as input